# set 404 error with double slashes .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

how I can set **404 error** in **.htaccess** with double slashes in URL? Problem is that my cur **.htaccess** not empty?

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # redirect from index.(php|asp|aspx|html|htm), main.(php|asp|aspx|html|htm), home.(php|asp|aspx|html|htm)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.(php|asp|aspx|html|htm)$ $1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)main\.(php|asp|aspx|html|htm)$ $1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)home\.(php|asp|aspx|html|htm)$ $1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)default\.(php|asp|aspx|html|htm)$ $1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www|dev)\.site\.ru$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*?)((?:index|default|home)\.(?:php|html?))?$ http://site.ru/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you mean by `404 error in .htaccess with double slashes in URL`?

Comment: For example, I have these URLs: `http://site.ru/abc.php, http://site.ru/123/dac.php`. If I put `http://site.ru////abc.php, http://site.ru//abc.php, http://site.ru///123////dac.php, http://site.ru//123//dac.php` I need generate 404 error. Is that clear?